# Every point in a Tychonoff Space is contained in a compact set

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

This should be very elementary, but I just can't see it:

Is every point in a Tychonoff Space contained in a compact set?

I tried to look for a counterexample and figured that it cannot be locally compact and singleton sets should not be closed $-$ but I couldn't find anything. I'd be grateful for any pointer in the right direction.

*Motivation*: The background is an Example in Conway's *A course in functional analysis* (p. 101, Ex. 1.5) in which he states that the space $C(X)$ of continuous functions from a Tychonoff Space $X$ into $\mathbb C$ with the family of semi-norm $p_K(f)=\sup_{x\in K}|f(x)|$ for $K$ a compact set in $X$, is a locally convex space. That is $\cap_K\{f:p_K(f)=0\}=\{0\}$, but for this to be true I seem to need the above result...

Comment: In any space $\{x\}$ is compact for each point $x$ in the space. Are you sure that you're asking the right question?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Oh... I somehow stubbornly kept thinking that compact sets need to be closed which is how I came to my requirements for the counterexample. So every point is indeed contained in a compact $K$, which in turn by the Hausdorff property is closed, so that by complete regularity I can get a continuous function that does not vanish on $K$. Thank you!

Comment: You’re welcome!